# Angular 6 : date time picker, what are good customizable controls for date time picker?

Tags: angular, customization, datetimepicker

I want to add date picker and time picker - separate fields in my application. 
what are good options available? 
I have tried -  not supported in safari
Tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datetimepicker - but cant customize for colors/css

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the best datepicker I have been worked with, it's the Angular Material Datepicker: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Also, if you add Angular Material you can use the other components providing by Angular Material that are very good, responsive, easy to use and customize.

Comment: This one looks good, I will give it a try. I need a separate timepicker  as well

Comment: @German Quinteros Were you able to use this and did it provide you with Hours Minutes and Seconds. I did not see any API in the material link above that specified those items.